# Definir constante PHP com valor de arquivo INI

Tags: php

tenho uma classe Config na qual defino a constante DEBUG com valor true ou false. Essa constante é acessada em várias páginas do sistema com:

```
Config::DEBUG;
```

Gostaria de definir essa constante com o valor que tenho em um arquivo .ini que tambem guarda as configurações do DB.

```
class Config
{
    const DEBUG = true;
}
```

Gostaria de definir a constante DEBUG como:

```
$ini = parse_ini_file('config.ini');
$ini['debug'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde,

Existe a forma de abrir o arquivo e ler o que está dentro dele, no PHP existe a função [parse_ini_file](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-ini-file.php) que permite ler os dados de um arquivo INI e retornar um array com os dados obtidos, vejo um exemplo simples e fácil de como utilizar esse método

```
$config = parse_ini_file('config.ini', true);
define('HOST',$config['DB']['HOST']);
var_dump(HOST);
```

arquivo INI

```
[DB]
HOST=localhost
PASSWORD=senha
```